css does not load in firebase deploy
I just build my react-next app and it works just fine. But when I do firebase deploy or firebase emulators:start, it only load the html.
The css url is all right, and it is correctly load in the request, it even appears in the element on inspection mode. But it is not applied to de site itself.
Here is the website: https://a1b2c3kkk98.web.app
And here is the github repo: https://github.com/Devs10042024/Adamo
I'm really new at git, so any bad habits you may see I'm guilty
The build folders is structured as following:
next
 |
  -cache
  -server
     |
      - index.html
  -static
     |
      -.css files
  -types

and the firebase.json is:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".next/server/app",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}



Your question needs contain the source code of the site you built and deployed, not a link to what you did deploy.  We should be able to take what you have and build/deploy it for ourselves to reproduce the issue.  Please edit the question to show these details.

@DougStevenson Got it! I just edited the question with the github repo.

Not a GitHub link. The text of the code needs to be copied into the question and formatted to be easy to read.  If your GH goes away in the future, this question becomes useless to future readers - we want to retain all the knowledge of this question for the future.

@DougStevenson But the code itself is very long. And there is not a specific piece of it that is causing trouble. Actually this is the main problem, there's none error apparent so I'm lost on where to look for. I understand what you are saying for the need, the only thing that comes to my mind is the link in the html header poiting to the css files, which are right, and the logs from inspection saying the css was received. You think this would make any difference?

That's why there is a requirement here to provide a complete minimal reproducible example.  It's your job to produce an example of sufficiently small size that it becomes more clear where the problem is.   Strip out everything that doesn't matter and show only the things that do.  Without this, the question is (at best) not going to be answered, and (at worst) closed as "needing debugging details".
